# No rotation methods called for view controller, presented with UIModalPresentationFormSheet in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios8

I am presenting `UINavigationController` with `modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationFormSheet` on **iPad** with **iOS 8** . In the root view controller, I need to find the moment when the screen rotation is performed, but I am not receiving any events that I'm expecting:

1. `-didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` is deprecated and not called
2. The new `-viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` and `-traitCollectionDidChange:` are not called because view seems to not transform in size.
3. `-application:didChangeStatusBarOrientation:` is called too early, not at the end of the rotation.

How can I find the moment of rotation end?

Comment: Does - (void)traitCollectionDidChange:(UITraitCollection *)previousTraitCollection get called?

Comment: Where you able to solve this? I'm facing a similar issue. Basically UIModalPresentaitonFormSheet is not rotating for me at all.

Comment: @LukeIrvin I'm sorry, I don't think I was able to solve it in iOS 8. Also it's been a while since I asked this question, so my memory leaked.